# A List of Standard or "Cliche" Homeomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, learning

Learning topology has been hard. I just cannot see how some people can come up with complex functions that link one space to another, in a homeomorphic sense.

The explanations are always "Well if you define this kind of function it satisfies continuity, bijectivity so there"
Which is irrefutable simply because that person is (mathematically) right.

I've always been wanting the "how did that function pop in your head."

What motivated you to think of such a function in the first place? A wild and lucky guess? Well that's not mathematical or logical, it can't be.

My conclusion is that these people "know" some of the well-known, most seen, most common homeomorphisms by heart and tweaks it here and there to build a new one to adapt. So I guess that's why they cannot answer to my "but *how* did you *find* that function?" I also often see "$X$ and $Y$ are clearly homeomorphic so..." in a discussion, where, to those practiced minds it is indeed crystal clear but to me, I cannot say "hmm, yes because well...uh huh, here's an example of a homeomorphism between $X,Y$ so yes, go on..."

I'm like, "but what's the homeomoprhism? I don't know where to start from scratch! What is the train of thought??"

Words like *obvious* bijection, or *natural way* of mapping only makes sense once one has seen these specifically and gotten comfortable with it. It's hard to explain why it's obvious because it *is* obvious but that's an issue when the less experienced is not comfortable with the notion of *just obvious*.

This is the problem with a lot of my professors too. They've been doing it for decades. Most may be born with topolo-genes (as I call it) who gets most of the abstract concepts in the speed of light. Perhaps that's why they don't understand why students like me say "*it's obvious to you and you indeed sound convincing and I cannot argue back, but I simply can't feel comfortable*"

In a nuthsell, at this level, things just seem to come out of nowhere(but still, correct and rigorous).

So my response now is to at least familiarize myself with these common homeomorphisms. Just remember them for now, use them like an idiot and gradually gain comfort.

---

So my request here is this: Would people provide me as much examples as possible(proof not necessary but appreciated of course) of most basic, common homeomorphisms between spaces?

For instance, the homeomorphism between a disk in a plane and a square? or something in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

It would be great if I can get "a homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$ is given by $f$" for the spaces you think are standard and know by heart. Even without thinking maybe.

I am thinking this should help me build on intuition and topolo-sense (take it as a topology version of spider-sense) which I lack severely.

Comment: You're not born with topolo-jeans; you put them on and break them in.

Comment: The question is not without interest but will probably be considered too broad.

Comment: Hi, any way you would suggest to narrow down? I am essentially wanting answers that would provide specific homeomorphisms to spaces that are most commonly seen in textbooks for instance. Or those that are "important" as it comes up time to time, or leads to constructing many others. Any suggestions to re-word it are welcome

Comment: @JohnTrail I think your question is fine, now.  It was hard to find the specific question in the long exposition (no offense), but it should be clear now that I've broken it up.

Comment: @JohnTrail One way to narrow the question would be to specify the pairs of spaces yourself (I see you've already given one example).

Comment: Learning math in general is hard, and it's generally hard for exactly this reason.  What mathematicians try to do is find a progression of logical steps from premise to conclusion.  However, it is *very often* the case that the way in which you find that next step is not systematic or logical, but via a stroke of insight.  It is not our job to simply use tools that take us from the problem statement to the solution, our job is to *make* those tools, often seemingly from nowhere.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Topolo-jeans are a nice example of cobordism between $S^1 \sqcup S^1$ and $S^1$.